# MATLAB: Changing a graph's name to a string from a cell array

Tags: matlab, graph, cell-array

So I have this:

names - which is a cell array of size 39x1, with each cell containing a string. For example names{1} = 'x0'

So my code so far looks like:

```
  for i = 1:39
      %gets all the names out the cell array
      names{i} = graphNames
      %create a new graph
      G = graph
      ********
  end
```

Where the *******s are is where I want to rename the graph with the variable graphNames, but no matter what I do the graph ends up being called graphNames, not x0. When I say graph I'm referring to a graph with nodes and edges... Any help would be amazing!

Comment: can you add the actual code you use for the plot instead of *** ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the line `names{i} = graphNames`. What happends is that every cell in the struct 'names' is given the name graphNames. Hence, your graphs ends up being called graphNames.

```
 for i = 1:39
          %gets all the names out the cell array
          graphNames=names{i} 
          %create a new graph
          G = graph
          ********
      end
```

This piece of code stores all the names which are located in the struct 'names' in the graphNames vector. Subsequently, you need to extract the names from the graphNames vector. However, I don't see any code of you doing this. Hence, I cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it with this code

```
for index = 1:length(names)
        s.(names{index}) = graph;
    end
```

thanks for the help though!